# Map a Map<Long, List<POJO>> through JPA eclipselink

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, one-to-many

I have a similar requirement as that of problem statement defined in 
[I want to map a Map<Long, List<POJO>> through JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068642/i-want-to-map-a-maplong-listpojo-through-jpa)

I am using eclipselink, I also had to create a separate class ItemAttributes , but in this class atleast I have to use primarykey for table ITEM_ATTRIBUTE. However the configuration is able to fetch the results in map, but while creating new record the eclipselink tries to consider the ItemAttributes as entity & hence ends up in inserting value for primarykey(which is null) in table ITEM_ATTRIBUTE which I don't want , I want only the list of - List attributes to be inserted. Surprisingly I cannot make the primary key as read only declared in ItemAttributes class.

Any idea how to avoid this? Further I cannot make the descriptor class ItemAttributes as read only as it will skip the creation part of entire table ITEM_ATTRIBUTE I am using eclipselink workbench for configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an Entity class to represent the relationship as in the answer to the other post.

What is your exact model/data model.

Your intermediate class will need an Id, you can use an @GeneratedValue if you have no logical one.

Comment: I have added an intermediate entity class, but while saving/updating I don't want the entire entity class to play role in CRUD operations, indeed I want only  @OneToMany relation  private List<ItemAttribute> attributes; to be used for inserting/updating and other attributes such as id should be ignored. Further the entity class cannot be marked as read only , as it will not allow any row to be inserted in ITEM_ATTRIBUTE table.