# How to persist a map with lists as values using Annotations?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have three model classes, Student, Workplace, Week, which I try to persist using `Annotations`. Each Student can have multiple workplaces per week, and so Student class has a field `Map<Week, List<Workplace>>`. But I don't find a solution to map this into the DB.

I did manage to persist a `@ManyToMany`relationship between Student and Workplace using `JoinTable` with Student_id, Workplace_id and Week_id as columns in the DB table, but what that maps is just a field `Map<Week, Workplace>` in class Student.

Here are the simplified model classes with the `Annotations` I last tried. The error I get is `Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: model.Student.studentsWorkplaces[java.util.List]`.

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id 
    private Integer id;     
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "STUDENTS_WORKPLACES", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "WEEK"))
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "WORKPLACE")
    private Map<Week, List<Workplace>> studentsWorkplaces;
//      Getters, Setters
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Workplace {    
    @Id
    private Integer id;     
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="studentsWorkplaces")
    private Map<Week, Student> workplaceStudents;
//      Getters, Setters
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Week {
    @Id
    private String week_year;   
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="studentsWorkplaces")
    private List<Student> students;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="studentsWorkplaces")
    private List<Workplace> workplaces;
//      Getters, Setters
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No JPA does not support that. See this doc https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Nested_Collections.2C_Maps_and_Matrices which explains why.

And already asked and answered in this question [I want to map a Map<Long, List<POJO>> through JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068642/i-want-to-map-a-maplong-listpojo-through-jpa)

Comment: OK, thanks! Unfortunately the thread you pointed me to didn't come up in my searches, also wasn't suggested here when asking, but it is indeed a working solution to my problem!